# Error while inserting 09 in Array list using add()?

Tags: java

i have an error while trying to insert 09 in my ArrayList's add method how to resolve it 
when i google for it its give me solution like its a octal no and i need to chage this to decimal no
how do i do this please any one help me ...

```
import java.util.*;
class MyArrayList{
   public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add(new Integer(09));
        System.out.println(al);
   }
}


output:MyArrayList.java:5:error integer too large:09
```

Comment: Hence your code will work if instead of 09 you put just 9, why is it like this?, follow link above.

Comment: Yes. Integer literals beginning with a "0" are treated as octal.

Answer (score 2):

Because values leading 0 are considered to be octal numbers. And octal numbers range from 0-7.  if it considers your given value as octal , even though it is not valid octal number.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc of the Integer constructor:

> Constructs a newly allocated Integer object that represents the int
>   value indicated by the String parameter. The string is converted to an
>   int value in exactly the manner used by the parseInt method for radix
>   10.

So in case you wanted to insert 9 (base 10) with a leading 0, omit the '0'. If your number is indeed an octal number, create the Integer object by parsing:

```
Integer outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(inputHex, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `ArrayList`. The problem is with `09` alone, for example a more characteristic example of the same problem:

```
int num = 09;
```

Because numeric literals starting with 0 are treated as octal numbers, and 9 is too big for that, as octal digits are from 0 to 7. So for the same reason `08` would give the same error, and `07` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Numbers starting with 0 in Java are considered as octal numbers and 9 is not an octal digit(only 0-7 are).
Numbers starting with 0x in Java are considered hexadecimal(the digits are 0-9 and A to F).
From Java SE 7, Numbers starting with 0b are considered binary(the digits are 0 and 1).`

Hence your number 09 is recognised as octal and 9 doesn't exist in octal digits.